# Change slug with custom field

Tags: posts, php, permalinks, post-meta, slug

I want to change the slug of a post with a custom field.

In example, if the custom field is "keyword" my post link will become: ***mysite.com/keyword.***

If the custom field is empty, i want to generate a random key like ***mysite.com/xV5f7A***.

How can i do that without change the wordpress core?

Any ideas are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The slug is saved on the wp_posts while custom fields are on the wp_posts_meta. If you want to make it like that you can use an action hook on save_post that will get the value of the custom fields and saves it as the post slug.

Here is the code

```
add_action('save_post', 'set_slug');

function set_slug($post_id){
    $new_slug = get_post_meta($post_id,'custom-slug', true);    
    $post_args = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => $new_slug,
    );

    wp_update_post($post_args);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks it's clear now. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Won't this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: I guess you are right. Maybe this is doable with a `$wpdb` function that skips the save_post hook.

Comment: Make sure to add `remove_action('save_post', 'set_slug');` inside the function so it doesn't go into an infinite loop.