# Custom field as Slug

Tags: custom-field, front-end, slug

I would like to ask if it's possible for a custom field to become a slug. Like if I have a custom field of "when" whose value is "today", I would like the address of the post to be example.com/taxonomy/today

I know slug is editable via permalink portion, but I plan on doing a frontend user posting, I want to try WP User Frontend Pro but it seems like it doesn't have the slug feature, but it has the custom field feature.. that's why I'm asking if it's possible for a custom field to become a slug.

I've tried suggestions on other posts, nothing seemed to work.

Comment: What other suggestions have you tried?

Comment: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61148/change-slug-with-custom-field?rq=1)
My dashboard loaded forever when I tried that